# NEI isnt showing up the items on the right when installed :(

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

For a while I have had NEI working and it worked like it should have then one day the left side with the cheats (ex. "turn off rain") disappeared then it wouldn't come back I tried to look in the options wouldn't work... so I assumed it was the file so I reinstalled it then both the item list and the cheat list disappeared and also the options button. I tried reinstalling it again. Same old same old. I tried universal files and just regular (well if they are both universal one of them said it so I thought they were different). Anyways, I am panicking that it is the version (1.7.10) I NEED HELP! I need this a lot because I am dealing with complicated mods like witchery and ars magica and thaumcraft... PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by a hotkey. If you open chests it will work though. If you want the NEI tab back you should press <kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>E</kbd> to open up the options. Also while you are using the options change the hotkey to hide NEI to something more comfortable for you.